# Parse a string without using SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java, parsing

I have a problem for my computer science class that can be solved efficiently using `SimpleDateFormat` but I am not allowed to use it as it has not been taught in my lessons.

Basically the problem is this...

Complete the following method that takes a String parameter that is a time in American 12 hour format, such as "06:12 PM."

The method returns a String with the same time in standard international 24 hour form. For example, given the parameter in the example above, the method would return "18:12." Values with AM correspond to times from 00:00 to 11:59 and PM for times from 12:00 to 23:59.

Recall the method Integer.parseInt() takes a String parameter and returns the integer equivalent.

And then simply I am supposed to create a method like so...

```
public static String convertTime(String amerFormat)
{

}
```

I simply do not understand how I would use .parseInt() to solve this problem and anything I try and research only uses `SimpleDateFormat`. Is that the only possible solution to this problem? How would I write the method without it...

Comment: Do you mean `SimpleDateFormat`?

Comment: amerFormat.replace("AM","").replace("PM",""); ??

Comment: yes sorry simpledateformat

Comment: You first need to determine if the `String` `endsWith` `AM` or `PM`, you'll then need to remove the suffix and split the `String` on the `:` token.  This will give you the hour and minute values.  Then based on the time of day part (AM or PM), you will need to increment the hour by 12 and the put it all back together

Comment: As an aside you shouldn’t have wanted to use `SImpleDateFormat` anyway. That class is notoriously troublesome and fortunately long outdated. Had it been allowed, I would have recommended `DateTimeFormatter` and `LocalTime` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try approaching the problem as if the values you are trying to parse don't represent a time. Instead, try to parse three separate values (hour, minute, AM/PM). How would you do that?

You know that the hour is two digits and ends with a ':'. So extract those two characters and parse as an int.

Then skip the ':' and repeat for the minutes.

Finally, check if the last two characters are AM or PM.

Now that you have all the pieces, turn them into standard international time form.

**Edit:** If you are trying to be more efficient, there are shortcuts.

If the time is AM, and the hour is not 12, then the numbers will be identical. If the hours are 12, then change them to 00.

Otherwise if the time is PM, drop the last three characters and replace the first two digits with the current value + 12 (unless the hours were 12, in which case they should not be changed).

Comment: So how would I even use Integer.parseInt() because in my lessons we used it to turn like "100" into 100, but never to separate strings into character groups. And everything I research gives a bare bones explanation

Comment: Take a look at `String.substring()` for extracting part of a String from a larger String.

Comment: @EnzoRomano You could also consider looking at [`String#split`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)).  The reason you're been made to do this, is `String` parsing is a common task with a number of possible approaches, based on your needs.  You HAVE to give it a go and try a few things, fail and try again, it's the only way to learn and understand (it's also the reason why you won't get a direct answer from us - because it won't help you in the long run)

Comment: Thank you for the String.substring suggestion that was all I needed. @MadProgrammer My end goal was to figure out the code myself but I am a new programmer and didn't know what to research so thats why I asked on here. Sorry you feel like I was asking for written code

Comment: I solved the problem by using string.substring() and if there was a PM, I added 12 hours to the time. Thanks @Jason

Answer (score 1):

I would first split the string into two pieces on the space. This gives you 06:12 as one part and AM or PM as the second part.

I would then split the first part on the colon to get hours and minutes separately and then convert those to hours and minutes as integers.

Turn hours == 12 to 0. (I'll show why shortly.)

If the AM/PM part is PM (I'd do it case insensitive), add 12 to the hours.

Then System.out.printf("%02d:%02d", hours, minutes). (Or use String's format method.)

Why turn 12 hours into 0? In the use, we write 10 minutes after midnight as "12:10 AM". But in 24-hour time, it's written as "00:10". And 10 minutes after noon is "12:10 PM" or "12:10" in 24-hour clock.

For methods you need, look at:

Integer.parseInt(String) to convert from strings to numbers

Strings.split() to split a string based on a regular expression, so you can do entireString.split(" ") to split on the space and then from the first of those, "results[0].split(":") to split into hours and minutes.

String.format() for formatting your new value.